# Что же такое ссылки?

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки, ref

В некоторых источниках я слышал, что ссылки - это просто обертка над указателями. Т.е. это теже указатели, но автоматически получают адресс переменной и сами разыменовываются для получения значения.
В других же источниках говорится, что ссылка - это просто второе имя для переменной и она не занимает ни байта памяти.
Сам я придерживаюсь второго мнения, но хотелось бы знать точно. Так что же такое ссылки?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что первое определение придумано только для того чтобы объяснить как ссылки работают, и не имеет ничего общего с реальной реализацией

Comment: Зацепился за *ссылка - это просто второе имя для переменной и она не занимает ни байта памяти*. Как тогда реализуется передача по ссылке? без единого байта памяти? Ссылка на динамически выделенную переменную?

Comment: В пределах использования ссылки, никакого дополнительного указателя не создаётся, но если передаём ссылку в функцию, то это идентично передаче указателя. Первое и второе определение, не противоречат друг другу.

Comment: Занимает ссылка память в конкретном случае или нет - решает реализация. Выражение ссылки через указатель применяют тогда, когда указатели уже изучены и нужно по-простецки ознакомить человека с ссылками. И указатели и ссылки оперируют адресами, но это разные сущности и делают они это по-разному.

Comment: Это не дубликат вопроса.

Answer (score 5):

Ссылка C++ позволяет создать псевдоним для переменных в программе. Не может быть неинициализированной, в отличие от указателя.
Оба определения правильные, но первое написано каким-то языком для "чайников" может вводить в заблуждение. 
Тут подробнее
http://cppstudio.com/post/429/

Прогоните кусок кода. Чтобы лучше понять.

```
int number = 1;
int& ref = number; // Создать ссылку
cout << "Переменная number содержит " << number << endl;
cout << "Другое имя содержит " << ref << endl;
ref += 500; // изменяем значение переменной посредством изменения значения в ссылке
cout << "Переменная number содержит " << number << endl;
cout << "Псевдоним для number содержит " << ref << endl;
```